# Oracle floating point comparison

Tags: oracle, comparison, precision, point, floating

I have a very strange situation with big numbers.
Query

```
select edge_id from edges where rownum = 1
```

returns
**2.57775300147101E21**

One can suggest that query

```
select * from edges where edge_id = 2.57775300147101E21
```

or

```
select * from edges where edge_id = 2577753001471010000000
```

will return a row.

But it returns "NO rows selected"...

Let us continue:

```
select to_char(edge_id) from edges where rownum = 1
```

returns
**2577753001471010316917**

This is unexpected behavior for me.
How can I query the table in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The displayed value of 2.57775300147101E21 is just that - a **displayed** value. The actual value is 2577753001471010316917, as shown in your `TO_CHAR(...` query, so to retrieve this row (and possibly others) you'll need to use the correct value:

```
SELECT *
  FROM EDGES
  WHERE EDGE_ID = 2577753001471010316917
```

Or you could use the correct value in scientific notation:

```
SELECT *
  FROM EDGES
  WHERE EDGE_ID = 2.577753001471010316917E21
```

Or you could a ranged query, such as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM EDGES
  WHERE EDGE_ID BETWEEN 2.5E21
                    AND 2.6E21
```

Whatever tool you're using to query your database is apparently showing "large" values using scientific notation. But the value of 2577753001471010316917 is the correct value you need to use to retrieve the row you want.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5c426f68d0f25cfbdc5dd78c63cd369)

Answer (score 1):

First answer is absolutely correct - Just change number format settings to TME(for scientific notation) or TM9.
Example for sql*plus: format TM9:

```
SQL> show numf
numformat ""
SQL> select 2577753001471010316917 x from dual;

         X
----------
2.5778E+21

SQL> set numf tm9
SQL> select 2577753001471010316917 x from dual;

                                                               X
----------------------------------------------------------------
2577753001471010316917

SQL> set numf tme
SQL> select 2577753001471010316917 x from dual;

                                                               X
----------------------------------------------------------------
2.577753001471010316917E+21
```

Comment: I don't understand you. I just want to query 2.57775300147101E21 **PRECISELY**. How do I know apriori that 2.57775300147101E21 is equal to 2577753001471010316917? Why it is not equal to 2577753001471010316721 or whatever digits after 257775300147101? )))

Comment: @AndrewKlimov - you *are* querying 2.57775300147101E21 precisely; and there are no rows that match that value. The client is displaying the actual table value rounded to the number of digits it's configured to show after the decimal point; if you then filter on that rounded value it won't find anything, unless you use a range as Bob showed. The issue if the display, not the data. (This is similar to people asking why filtering a date column on `to_date('15-Apr-21')` doesn't find anything when that is the value displayed by a query; because the display truncated to the day, hiding the time.)

Comment: @AndrewKlimov just open your SQL client settings and find number formatting settings.

Comment: Thanks to all for helpful answers! I found workaround just applying display "Number fields to_char" in PL/SQL Developer.